# Changing font on textField

Tags: javafx, fonts, textfield, font-size

Want to make a my font on my textFields bigger so google:d and came up with this:

```
Font font1 = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
        textField.setFont(font1);
```

Java says "The method setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font) in the type TextInputControl is not applicable for the arguments (java.awt.Font)". Were working for others but might not because mine is an integer?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure about all of your implementation, you'll want to double-check your packages and imports.

Your `Font` object appears to be from the `java.awt` package. You need to use the `javafx.scene.text.Font` object instead.

Use `import javafx.scene.text.Font;` for your import statement.

You can then set the font with one line:

```
textField.setFont(Font.font("Serif", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
```